# Minimizing home heating costs

Tags: energy-efficiency, convection, heat

I live in an old rental house with 12 foot ceilings and zero ceiling fans. I am trying to conserve as much energy as possible as heating costs are expensive. I have placed plastic on all of my windows and close doors, etc. but I am wanting to do more. My question is this, if I hang items from my ceiling, will that help keep my energy costs down? I am not sure what I would hang but almost like panels of some kind. The intent behind hanging panels from the ceiling is to help keep the heat from rising to ceiling level. My landlord is not likely to install ceiling fans. Would it make a difference even if I don't do a whole complete "drop-down" ceiling? Like, if I hang 2 or 3 panels, will that help in the slightest?

Comment: Could you clarify/give an example of  how "hanging items from the ceiling" might help lower energy costs?

Comment: This may be a better fit on [Sustainability.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Negotiate with the landlord to invest in a programable thermostat and a few ceiling fans will help in reducing the heating bill. Also, turn the heat to barely low (that without the need for wearing a coat indoors) and use a portable heating device to keep warm may help too.

Answer (score 1):

A suspended ceiling at a height of 2.4m is the most efficient way of saving the heating cost. Because right now most of the heat in your home goes up to the high ceiling.

If you don't have access to supplies or dry-wall (gypsum-board), you can hang a lightweight frame of boards of 4cm by 4cm lumber and cover them with plastic.

this photo is a typical suspended ceiling. If you need yu can use the space above for storage.

[image: ceiling]

Comment: It is well known that hot air rises & usually the hottest region of a room is near the ceiling. Reducing the ceiling height, as this answer suggests brings the warmest zone closer to floor level, but it also reduces the amount of air that needs to be heated. Converse to this, high ceilings are a practical way to have a cooler room in a hot climate.

Comment: As this is a rental home, it is probably more likely to get the nod over a ceiling fan than a suspended ceiling. But you may try as it is a good idea.

Comment: @r13, in my area many of the rentals are rent control. meaning people pass them on to their kids in their wills.

Comment: @kamran Just serving as a reminder.